# speech recognition (sometimes speaking, sometimes not)

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-synthesis

Am I only the one who's experiencing this weird problem? Sometimes it speaks, sometimes its not. Also about 3-5 seconds after I start debugging it automatically executing speech == "Hello Enzo" without saying anything. (No voice from the background so Im sure Im the only one who's speaking)

And sometimes when I speak it doesn't work I had to start debugging it again and again until it hear and answer me.

Here's below a few debug

```css
JARVIS.vshost.exe Information: 0 : SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection.
The thread 0x87b0 has exited with code 0 (0x0). <<---This is the Its Good to see you again sir
The thread 0x7aec has exited with code 0 (0x0). <<---THIS is the Hello Enzo reply without speaking or saying anything
The thread 0x9544 has exited with code 0 (0x0). <<--This is Yes Good evening
The thread 0x749c has exited with code 0 (0x0). <<--This is Yes Good evening I only said. 1 "Hello Enzo" But it speak 2 times
The thread 0x8638 has exited with code 259 (0x103). <<---Randomly spam
The thread 0x57c has exited with code 259 (0x103).  <<---Randomly spam
The thread 0x91bc has exited with code 259 (0x103)  .<<---Randomly spam
The thread 0x70c8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).  <<---Randomly spam
The thread 0x907c has exited with code 259 (0x103).  <<---Randomly spam
The thread 0x8c40 has exited with code 259 (0x103).  <<---Randomly spam
```

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;


namespace JARVISV2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        SpeechSynthesizer ENZO = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        Random rnd = new Random();

        string QEvent;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Commands.txt")))));
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
            _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

            ENZO.Speak("Its Good to see you again sir");

            ENZO.Rate = -1;
            ENZO.Volume = 100;
        }


        void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            int ranNum = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            string time = now.GetDateTimeFormats('t')[0];
            string speech = e.Result.Text;
            {
                if (speech == "Hello Enzo")
                {
                    if (ranNum > 6) { ENZO.SpeakAsync("How may I help you"); }
                    else if (ranNum < 5) { ENZO.SpeakAsync("Im here sir"); }
                    else if (ranNum < 7) { ENZO.SpeakAsync("Welcome back sir"); }
                    else if (ranNum < 8) { ENZO.SpeakAsync("Need assistance?"); }
                    else if (ranNum < 10) { ENZO.SpeakAsync("Whats up"); }
                }
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick search for the error at the top of your trace: "SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection" shows some people with similar problems.

Try setting the culture for your GrammarBuilder, so instead of this:

```
_recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Commands.txt")))));
```

try this:

```
GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Commands.txt")));
            gb.Culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(gb));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried but still it shows "SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection" I wrote it inside Form1_Load

Comment: are you able to run the speech recognition in Windows, and have it recognize your input? You should be able to run it by Windows key and search for 'Speech'

Comment: Yes surely it can recognize my voice. I tried going to control panel speech. It's probably somewhere the code but I don't know exactly where.